# error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined' - Using "?." operator

Tags: javascript, typescript

I use TS 4.0.2, and get an error while using "?." operator:

[image]

When I use the old nullish check, it run:

```
if (a && a.length) {
```

What do I miss?

Comment: Does `if (a?.length)` without the `> 0` work?

Comment: It may work, but it doesn't cover all the cases as ">0"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the [documentation | 3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html) you will see that.

> That might result in dividing undefined, which is why in
> strictNullChecks, the following is an error.

```
function barPercentage(foo?: { bar: number }) {
  return foo?.bar / 100;
  //     ~~~~~~~~
  // Error: Object is possibly undefined.
}
```

I believe that this is the case.